# Sign Enumeration

Tags: co.combinatorics, diophantine-equations, generating-functions, integer-programming

What is the number of solutions of $(a_i)_{i=1}^n$ such that
$$\sum_{i=1}^nia_i\le b,\quad a_i\in\{-1,1\},\quad \sum_{i=1}^n{a_i}=c$$
given $b,c\in\mathbf Z$?

Is there a generating function solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The g.f. equals
$$\frac1{1-y}\prod_{i=1}^n \left(xy^i + (xy^i)^{-1}\right).$$
That is, the number of solutions is given by the coefficient of $x^cy^b$.

Comment: Thank you, Max. I came up with the same formulation. However, I was expecting further development to get a simpler and direct expression like many other generating function solutions produce. Perhaps, this is the most we can obtain. Short of further analytical simplification, if we enumerate it with a computer, does this generating function formulation help with reducing complexity of the enumeration compared to generating solutions of the inequality with brute force? Do we need a symbolic computation software?

Comment: Call the above generating function $g(x,y)$. The coefficient of $x^cy^b$ is the complex contour integral $\frac{1}{(2\pi i)^2}\oint_{|x|=\delta_1<1}\oint_{|y|=\delta_2<1}\frac{g(x,y)}{x^{c+1}y^{b+1}}dxdy$. But there does not seem to be a simple expression for this integral. Maybe it is useful in obtaining asymptotics for large $n$, $b$ or $c$. I would appreciate it, Max, if you could share your opinion on the benefit/usefulness of generating functions that does not produce simpler expression.

Comment: @Hans: I believe the formula is not so helpful for computation. It can lead to a dynamic programming algorithm for computing the coefficient, but this algorithm can be directly seen from the original problem formulation.

Comment: That was what I thought. I have a dynamic programming or recursive algorithm. Do you know if my contour integral is any good for finding the asymptotics for large $n$, $b$ or $c$?